# No. 1: What's the next in this letter sequence?

Tags: pattern, knowledge

Part of a series of similar puzzles - the answer to one will give you the type of thinking required for the others.

What's the next letter in this series? What's the relationship?

```
L
K
Z
R
A
O
T
E
L
A
I
D
L
N
A
S
Y
A
E
D
A
```

Comment: I will either give more letters in the pattern, or hints if no one gets it in a couple of days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next letter in the sequence is:

> I

Because the letters are:

> The second letter of the abbreviations for U.S. States, in alphabetical order:
>     `Alabama > AL > L`
>     `Alaska  > AK > K`
>     `Arizona > AZ > Z`
>   The last state in the list is Massachusetts, so the next is Michigan
>     `Michigan > MI > I`

Comment: Good work! That was fast!! Was it really that easy?